# Sort array value by another array key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have 2 arrays:

```
Array
(
    [field_bathrooms] => Bathrooms
    [field_bedrooms] => Bedrooms
    [field_king_beds] => King Beds
    [field_kitchen] => Kitchen
    [field_queen_beds] => Queen Beds
    [field_sleeps_max] => Sleeps
    [field_sofa_beds] => Sofa Beds
    [field_sqft] => Square Footage
    [field_twin_beds] => Twin Beds
)

Array
(
    [0] => Bathrooms
    [1] => Square Footage
    [2] => King Beds
    [3] => Sofa Beds
    [4] => Sleeps
    [5] => Twin Beds
    [6] => Queen Beds
    [7] => Kitchen
    [8] => Bedrooms
)
```

I want to sort 1st array by 2nd array's key, so final result is an array like this:

```
Array(
[field_bathrooms] => Bathrooms
[field_sqft] => Square Footage
[field_king_beds] => King Beds
[field_sofa_beds] => Sofa Beds
[field_sleeps_max] => Sleeps
[field_twin_beds] => Twin Beds
[field_queen_beds] => Queen Beds
[field_kitchen] => Kitchen
[field_bedrooms] => Bedrooms
)
```

I must confess that I'm relative new to PHP and MySQL.
Hopefully some one of you all could bring me back on track.

Comment: This might be a good reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: I highly recommend checking out Jacks answer, understand his will noticeably increase your proficiency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do what you want in one line:

```
$result = array_flip( array_replace( array_flip($arr2), array_flip($arr1) ) );

print_r($result);
```

To explain: 
Since you want to sort by the value in the array, and not by the key, we use [`array_flip`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) to flip the array and value in each of your arrays. Then, we use [`array_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php) to replace the values in the second array with the matching ones from the first array (keeping the current order). Then we use [`array_flip`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) to put the keys and values back how we started.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a custom sort function that references a map (inversed second array):

```
$map = array_flip($second_array);

uasort($first_array, function($a, $b) use ($map) {
    return $map[$a] - $map[$b];
});

print_r($first_array);
```

See also: [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/array_flip) [`uasort()`](http://php.net/uasort)

Answer (score 0):

your code can be something like this:

```
$indx;
for ($i = 0; i < Aarray1size; i++)
{

    $key = Array1[i];
    for ($j = 0; j < array2size; j++)
    {
         if(Array2[j] == $key)
          {
                index = j;
          }
    }
    Array1[i] = Array2[index];
    index = 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

aught to do it

```
<?

$arr1 = array(
    'field_bathrooms' => 'Bathrooms',
    'field_bedrooms' => 'Bedrooms',
    'field_king_beds' => 'King Beds',
    'field_kitchen' => 'Kitchen',
    'field_queen_beds' => 'Queen Beds',
    'field_sleeps_max' => 'Sleeps',
    'field_sofa_beds' => 'Sofa Beds',
    'field_sqft' => 'Square Footage',
    'field_twin_beds' => 'Twin Beds'
);

$arr2 = array(
    'Bathrooms',
    'Square Footage',
    'King Beds',
    'Sofa Beds',
    'Sleeps',
    'Twin Beds',
    'Queen Beds',
    'Kitchen',
    'Bedrooms',
);

$result = array();
foreach($arr2 as $val)
{
    foreach($arr1 as $k => $v)
    {
        if ($val == $v)
        {
            $result[$k] = $v;
            unset($arr1[$k]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = array
(
    'field_bathrooms' => 'Bathrooms',
    'field_bedrooms' => 'Bedrooms',
    'field_king_beds' => 'King Beds',
    'field_kitchen' => 'Kitchen',
    'field_queen_beds' => 'Queen Beds',
    'field_sleeps_max' => 'Sleeps',
    'field_sofa_beds' => 'Sofa Beds',
    'field_sqft' => 'Square Footage',
    'field_twin_beds' => 'Twin Beds',
);

$array2 = array
(
    0 => 'Bathrooms',
    1 => 'Square Footage',
    2 => 'King Beds',
    3 => 'Sofa Beds',
    4 => 'Sleeps',
    5 => 'Twin Beds',
    6 => 'Queen Beds',
    7 => 'Kitchen',
    8 => 'Bedrooms',
);

$array3 = array();
foreach ($array2 as $val)
{
  $key = array_search($val, $array1);
  $array3[$key] = $val;
}

var_dump($array3);
```